# How to replace the object array using simple filter and spread operators

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, ecmascript-6

I need a suggestion for the below code. The objective here is to remove the specific array if the mentioned `menuKey` is present.

*Note:* `sdb.menu = 'account-links'` (Declared in another file);

```js
const { menu = [] } = remainingConfig[sdb.menu]?.params || {};
const keysToRemove = ['sidebarReferAFriend'];
const filteredMenu = menu.filter(({ menuKey }: IMenuLink) => !keysToRemove.includes(menuKey));
```

How can I assign the **`filteredMenu`** back to **`remainingConfig`** object?

I tried with some spread operator options and it's not giving the existing same structure. So please provide some help here when you have some time.

The object structure will be like attached image.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Why do you think you need to use spread syntax? *(`...` isn't an operator.)* Is some part of this structure immutable? If so, which parts? What (if anything) can you directly assign to vs. replacing with new copies?

Comment: The "menu" array should be immutable as per the client's request.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Is it *just* `menu`? If so, the first part of my answer works (we don't change the array, we create a new one). But usually there'd be more, so again, how much *more* of the structure is immutable? The whole thing? If so, how do you replace it? But I think I've given you enough to work with in the second part of my answer if more of it is immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can directly assign to the `remainingConfig[sdb.menu].params.menu` property, then since presumably you don't need to create the array if it's not there, only do the work if the array and everything leading up to it exists, then just assign back to `menu`:

```
const menuConfigParams = remainingConfig[sdb.menu]?.params;
const menu = menuConfigParams?.menu;
if (menu) {
    const keysToRemove = ['sidebarReferAFriend'];
    menuConfigParams.menu = menu.filter(({ menuKey }/*: IMenuLink*/) => !keysToRemove.includes(menuKey));
}
```

If the `remainingConfig` structure is deeply immutable, then we have to create a new object to replace it at every level of the nesting:

```
const menuConfig = remainingConfig[sdb.menu];
const menuConfigParams = menuConfig?.params;
let menu = menuConfigParams?.menu;
if (menu) {
    const keysToRemove = ['sidebarReferAFriend'];
    menu = menu.filter(({ menuKey }/*: IMenuLink*/) => !keysToRemove.includes(menuKey));
    const newConfig = {
        ...remainingConfig,
        [sdb.menu]: {
            ...menuConfig,
            params: {
                ...menuConfig.params,
                menu,
            }
        }
    };
    // ...then use whatever mechanism is in your environment to replace `remainingConfig`
    // with `newConfig`...
}
```

Notice how at each level we're making a shallow copy of the structure via spread syntax.